# MySQL query assistance - summing part of IN clause

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
emp_id | code   | min  
1234   | TLPAID | 480  
4321   | TLPAID | 480  
4321   | UPAB   | 4  
4321   | UUAB   | 50  
5555   | TLPAID | 480  
5555   | ALLEUP | 10
```

... there are hundreds of possible codes, but I am interested in summing 6 of them and checking to see if it's less than 10.

I have a query:

```
SELECT emp_id, sum(min) as time, SEC_TO_TIME(sum(min)*60) as time_formatted 
FROM codes 
WHERE code IN ('ALLEPD',  'ALLEUP',  'LATEBL',  'NCNS',  'UPAB',  'UUAB') 
GROUP BY emp_id HAVING time < 10
```

This query works great, unless the employee has none of those 6 codes - then they obviously wouldn't be returned. And that's my problem: I need them to be in the results because their time is 0 which is less than 10.

Now, an employee will always have the code `TLPAID`, so I was wondering if there was a way to include that code with the 6 mentioned above (that way the employee would be included in the query results), but still only sum those 6?

Desired results:

```
emp_id | min  
1234   | 0  
4321   | 54  
5555   | 10
```

Any thoughts on how i should approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to get a list of all emp_id from the codes table, and use that list as a "driving" table for a LEFT JOIN operation.

Something like this:

```
SELECT e.emp_id
     , IFNULL(SUM(c.min),0) AS time
     , SEC_TO_TIME(IFNULL(SUM(c.min),0)*60) AS time_formatted
  FROM (SELECT d.emp_id FROM codes d GROUP BY d.emp_id) e
  LEFT
  JOIN codes c
    ON c.emp_id = e.emp_id
   AND c.code IN ('ALLEPD',  'ALLEUP',  'LATEBL',  'NCNS',  'UPAB',  'UUAB')
 GROUP 
    BY e.emp_id
HAVING time < 10
```

**NOTES:**

The query in the lineview `e` gets a list of distinct `emp_id`. We can put that query in parenthesis, and use it in a FROM clause like it was a table. We are required to assign an alias (in this case, we just picked `e`) to this derived table.

The `LEFT JOIN` returns every `emp_id` from `e`, along with the matching rows from `codes`. (We chose to give that table reference an alias of `c`.)

The predicate in the WHERE clause gets moved to the ON clause of the JOIN, along with the predicate that "matches" rows from codes with the rows from e.

We wrap the `SUM()` expressions in an `IFNULL` function to return a zero when `SUM()` is NULL.

We add table aliases on all column references to 1) avoid "ambiguous column" errors, and (probably more importantly) help a reader decipher what the query is doing, the reader is not left wondering which table a column reference is referring to.

(To avoid returning a NULL for `emp_id`, we could add a `WHERE d.emp_id IS NOT NULL` to the inline view query.)

Comment: there's a typo in the join (e.emd_id does not exist) and I had to removed the `HAVING` clause. after that this works, tested

Comment: good catch, Kris. That was a typo, the query was desk checked only, not tested. Correction applied. Thanks!

Comment: @Gajetastic: rather than muck up this answer with another approach, I added another answer, which returns the same result as the query in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I might union those in separately, something like this:

```
SELECT emp_id, sum(min) as time, SEC_TO_TIME(sum(min)*60) as time_formatted FROM codes WHERE code IN ('ALLEPD',  'ALLEUP',  'LATEBL',  'NCNS',  'UPAB',  'UUAB') GROUP BY emp_id HAVING time < 10 

UNION

SELECT emp_id, 0 as time, 0 as time_formatted FROM codes WHERE code NOT IN ('ALLEPD',  'ALLEUP',  'LATEBL',  'NCNS',  'UPAB',  'UUAB') GROUP BY emp_id
```

Comment: +1 The desired resultset can be returned with a UNION operator, but there's no guarantee that the second query won't return an `emp_id` that isn't returned in the previous query. That second query would really need to be modified to omit emp_id not returned by the first query. This could be done with a NOT EXISTS predicate, or an anti-join. The query as it is right now doesn't meet the specification. (We don't have any guarantee that an emp_id won't have a code that is in the list, and a code that is not in the list.)

Comment: @spencer7593: agreed, it was meant to point towards a possible answer, not solve it completely. your answer is a lot better and if i don't get the exact results in a couple minutes i'll be deleting mine.

Comment: I don't think you should delete your answer, because this approach actually works better in some cases which are similar to the OP question.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the approach in my other answer, another way to get the same result, without an inline view and a JOIN operation:

```
SELECT c.emp_id
     , SUM( 
         IF(c.code IN ('ALLEPD','ALLEUP','LATEBL','NCNS','UPAB','UUAB'),c.min,0)
       ) AS time
     , SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(
         IF(c.code IN ('ALLEPD','ALLEUP','LATEBL','NCNS','UPAB','UUAB'),c.min,0)
       )*60) AS time_formatted 
  FROM codes c
 GROUP BY c.emp_id
HAVING time < 10
```

This will scan all the rows in the codes table; there is no predicate restricting which rows will be returned, so we will get all values of `emp_id` from the `codes` table.

The "trick" is in the SELECT list, where we `SUM` up the return from an `IF` expression. The `IF` expression returns the value of the `min` column whenever `code` is in the list. For other values of `code`, the expression returns 0.

If we ever have rows for a given `emp_id` where all of the rows for that emp_id have a `code` that appears in the list, and `NULL` as the value for `min`, then this query will return a `NULL` for the `SUM`. (As long as there is at least one row for the emp_id with a code that is not in the list, or at least one row with a not NULL value for a code in the list, that won't be a problem.)

Comment: Beat me to it, I was going to suggest this approach, no testing done but I expect it would out perform your other answer. Heres the {SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4eb3/3) I was going to use.

Comment: @GarethD: for small sets, the difference isn't going to be noticeable. My gut tells me that this approach will faster if there's a covering index on `(emp_id,code,min)`, because MySQL will likely optimize the `GROUP BY` using the index and avoid a "Using filesort" operation. And my gut tells me the other (LEFT JOIN) approach will be faster only if the number of rows with those six codes of interest is a very small subset (<5%) of the rows in the table. Actual performance would be best be gauged by testing and observation.

Answer (score 0):

do a left Join with original table with your current query which will identify the return null value for unmatched column then convert null to zero So that automatically your query sums zeros for unmatched records as well and other matched results will be your current query result . . PFB CODE

SELECT e.emp_id
     , IFNULL(SUM(c.min),0) AS time
     , SEC_TO_TIME(IFNULL(SUM(c.min),0)*60) AS time_formatted
  FROM (SELECT d.emp_id FROM codes d GROUP BY d.emp_id) e
  LEFT
  JOIN codes c
    ON c.emp_id = e.emp_id
   AND c.code IN ('ALLEPD',  'ALLEUP',  'LATEBL',  'NCNS',  'UPAB',  'UUAB')
 GROUP 
    BY e.emp_id
HAVING time < 10

Comment: Hmmm. The query in this answer has the exact same aliases assigned to the inline view and tables, and the exact same typo  (`= e.emd_id`)  as the query in my answer. Curious.

Comment: i am lazy to type in mobile pad. . And given some explanation with your answer !

Answer (score 0):

While I would probably prefer the join solution offered by spencer7593, I wanted to show an alternative approach anyway:

```
SELECT 
    `emp_id`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `code` IN('ALLEPD','ALLEUP','LATEBL','NCNS','UPAB','UUAB') 
        THEN COALESCE(`min`, 0) 
        ELSE 0 END) as `time`, 
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(`min`)*60) as `time_formatted` 
FROM `codes`
GROUP BY `emp_id`;
```

Output:

```
emp_id  time    time_formatted
1234    0       08:00:00
4321    54      08:54:00
5555    10      08:10:00
```

Tested in a mysql database initialized using:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `SO`;
CREATE DATABASE `SO`;
USE `SO`;

CREATE TABLE `codes` (
    `emp_id` INT,
    `code` VARCHAR(8),
    `min` int
);

INSERT INTO codes (`emp_id` , `code` , `min`)
VALUES
 (1234 , 'TLPAID' , 480)
,(4321 , 'TLPAID' , 480)
,(4321 , 'UPAB' , 4)
,(4321 , 'UUAB' , 50)
,(5555 , 'TLPAID' , 480)
,(5555 , 'ALLEUP' , 10);
```

Comment: I did the same thing in my other answer. The `SUM(min)` to return the `time_formatted` column needs to have `min` replaced with that same `CASE` expression. (You've got a clever use of COALESCE to avoid a NULL value, and that CASE expression is more portable than the (equivalent) MySQL specific `IF()` function in my answer.)